# Was Churchill a poor HR manager?

Tags: world-war-two, churchill

The key problem in the delegation of authority is to  match the delegatee's character and experience with the tasks appointed to him/her. I got an impression that Churchill's record in this field is less than impressive. Here are some examples of poor choices he made: Ian Hamilton for Gallipoli, Lindemann as chief scientific adviser, Fisher as First Sea Lord during WWI and Dudley Pound during WWII, Mountbatten for Dieppe and SEAC, Wingate for Burma.

Questions:

1. Are there examples of particularly apt personnel selections by Churchill to counter-balance my list?
2. Is this issue treated specifically in the historical literature? (We have works on Churchill & X for X ranging over at least {Soviet Union, America, British Empire, Jews} - what about X being Human Resources?)

Comment: This may be slightly subjective.

Comment: @Russell: In what sense?

Comment: how do you mesure HR management skill? I know that you've clarified it with your other questions, however, they also raise several questions. Thought the question may be slightly subjective, we do have a precedent that allows question like this, which is why I did not flag it. However, I wanted to see what other people thought about the question.

Comment: @Russell: I completely agree that HRM skill (as any other "soft" skill) does not lend itself easily or completely to objective measurement. However, one can get a rough measurement of X's HR skill by looking at the results that X's chosen lieutenants achieved in the tasks appointed to them. The men I listed all either failed signally (Hamilton, Moutbatten/Dieppe) or at least failed to achieve the great hopes that were pinned on them (Lindemann, Wingate) or turned out to be unable to work with the appointer (I mean Fisher). <TBC>

Comment: <Continued> I'm sure knowledgeable people may dispute some of my judgements in the examples, but to me there does seem to be a pattern emerging. That's why I'm asking for help in checking if there is indeed a pattern or not.

Comment: Well, you are more knowledgeable than me. :) Since the mods havent closed the question, nor has the question received any close votes, I think that it is an acceptable question.

Comment: @Russell: If now we could get some answers, it'd be even better. :)

Comment: I don't know whether Churchill was specifically poor at HR, but he did have poor _judgement_. He was somewhat _gungho_ and didn't think through the implications of his actions aka Gallipoli was simply poor judgement, in other words he got it wrong.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Churchill's judgement might have been faulty often (a broad and even more subjective topic which I didn't want to get into, restricting the question to the HR aspect, which is more amenable to analysis) - but Gallipoli was, as far as I know, a basically sound idea which was terribly botched in the execution by everyone involved (including Churchill).

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Wrong place at the wrong time, it was too heavily defended and there were other better options. Churchill was a poor politician and even worse military leader.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: I rather disagree; anyhow, that's exactly why I restricted myself to HR - it can sustain a relatively objective analysis.

Comment: I thought [Andrew Roberts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Roberts_%28historian%29)'s [Masters and Commanders: How Four Titans Won the War in the West, 1941-1945](http://www.amazon.com/Masters-Commanders-Four-Titans-1941-1945/dp/0061228583) was good on the soft skills or lack thereof in Roosevelt, Churchill, Marshall, and Brooke. My sense (perhaps mainly from this source) is that Churchill (here a bit like Hitler) saw himself as a considerable military expert e.g. through his writings, and that this tended to cause conflicts with some UK players. It may have influenced some HR choices too.

Comment: Off-topic for a main question: It seems surprising that Churchill installed [Lindemann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Lindemann,_1st_Viscount_Cherwell), who was born in Germany, as his top scientific adviser in WW II. Is there any (probing) biography that can be recommended in particular?

Comment: @Drux: You are quite right about Churchill considering himself as a military expert - much like Hitler and Stalin. Of all three he had the best credentials (at least he had graduated from Sandhurst and saw service on three continents as an officer, unlike a certain corporal a certain apprentice clergyman), but as to whether his military judgement was significantly better as a result, I don't know. Stalin, in my opinion, was very mediocre in military matters; Hitler, villain though he was, had some flashes of military brilliance (Liddel Hart treats the subject at some length in his major book).

Comment: @FelixGoldberg It's been a while since I read the books that contained references to Churchills leadership abilities and I'd have to re-read those sections to give you more specific answers. I do remember however, that he was a politician first and foremost and the second world war was won despite his interference rather than because of it. Re Stalin, he was just a dictator, his military leadership was non existent.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: If you mean that Stalin made no useful military contribution, you are absolutely right. But that doesn't mean he didn't interfere in the war effort - he did and a lot, since he considered himself a military genius, promoting himself to Marshal and later to Generalissimo. He styled himself Supreme High Commander in Chief and actually vetted all decisions. Once again, the net effect of his "generalship" was very very negative (there are people who'd dispute that, the same people who'd tell you that killing off 20 million of one's own people is a good way to industrialize).

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I'm aware of that, but like Churchill, his interference hindered the war effort, not improved it. Russia was eventually successful, but that was down soley to the quality of *some* of their generals and their massive resources rather than anything to do with Stalin. Bear in mind when Germany invaded, they were utterly ill prepared and suffered many losses, despite Stalin knowing that it was likely to happen. He just hoped it wouldn't.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Little argument then from me re:Stalin here (although modern historians are not so sure that Russia was ill-prepared, but let's not open a can of worms here :).

Comment: @Felix Thx & +1 for reference to Liddel Hart.

Comment: @Drux Re:Lindemann. C.P.Snow wrote a lot, and scathingly, about his performance in *Science and Government* where he sets up Lindemann as the bad pole and Tizard as the good pole. Later writers, drawing also on documents which were not available to Snow, have mollified somewhat his harsh judgement but on the whole it does seem that Lindemann was not the right man for his job.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, looks like it was subjective, but subjective good. :) Anyway, it's beyond my range of historical knowledge.

Comment: IIRC HRM post-dates WWII.  Maybe "Personnel management" would be less anachronistic?

Answer (score 3):

I recall a quote by one of Churchill's senior generals about his military prowess going something like this:

> "Churchill's amazing; he comes up with 10 completely original ideas every single day. 
> Of course, only one of them is any good; and Winston doesn't know which one it is."

I argue that the fundamental difference between the management styles of Churchill, Hitler and Stalin is that Churchill **generally** knew when to defer to his military advisors; Stalin **sometimes** knew when to defer; and Hitler didn't know the meaning of the word defer.

Given that most supervisors have great difficulty deferring to subordinates, that would make Churchill well above average; Stalin about average; and Hitler somewhere off the bottom of the scale.

Comment: Interesting point (not quite what I was asking for, I think) but nevertheless. Perhaps the quote is from Alanbrooke?

Comment: We could add that Roosevelt practically always deferred!

Answer (score 0):

His treatment of colonial troops in both wars was poor, some of the best troops available to him where colonial troops and he constantly wasted them in futile engagments in world War 1. He refused to listen to colonial generals, Monash who Churchill desperately wanted to sack was an Australian General of Jewish decent. The Australian prime minister grabbed Churchill by the throat and threatened him after a discussion about the deployment of Australian troops. I would rate Churchill overall as a poor HR man but he more than made up for it with his forceable will, and his genius at mass psychology.

Comment: Do you have sources for this?

Comment: Considering "*Breaker Morant*" was in both their lifetimes, I am surprised that ALL the Australian PM did was shake Churchill up a bit by the throat.